# How to make autocomplete search result to overlap the content of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

here is my code for autocomplete:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
       $("#SearchString").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("GetProducts","Search")',
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     <div class="itemtodisplay">
    <p>
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { id = "SearchString" }) 

        <input type="submit" value="Search" id="Search" />
    </p>
         </div>
}
```

The autocomplete list makes the content of the page to push down.. I want to make it like a Flip cart Search list. Like the autocomplete search result overlaps the content of each page. Please provide any suggestion.

Comment: set its position fixed in css and z-index:99999

Comment: @EhsanSajjad . I did like .itemtodisplay{position:fixed;z-index:9999}    Its not working.

Comment: if you provide a fiddle that will be easy to help out

Answer (score 0):

if I am right you want this isn't it.
append following code end of .autocomplete ")" like

).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

```
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

     var inner_html = 'No results';

     if (item.ListItemType != 'NoResult') {

         inner_html = '<a href="' + item.RoutUrl + '">' +
              '<div style="height:45px; padding: 2px;">' +
                Add what ever you want to show
             '</div></a>';

     }

     return $("<li></li>")
          .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
          .append(inner_html)
          .appendTo(ul);

 };
```

hope this will guide you.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the autocomplete-list pushing the other elements, you must give it `position:absolute`. From there, add margins, `top/left/right/bottom` as you please.